# how to use django-filters on django-tables2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views, django-tables2, django-filters

This is my view:

```
class PersonalView(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    model = Invoice
    template_name = 'invProj/index.html'
    table_class = InvoiceTable
    filterset_class = InvoiceFilter
    context_object_name = 'invoice'
    ordering = ['invoice_due_date']

    def get_table_data(self):
        return Invoice.objects.filter(invoice_owner__username=self.request.user).order_by('i
nvoice_due_date')
```

Now, `get_table_data` does the right thing, the invoices are filtered according to the user. But, the `InvoiceFilter(django_filters.FilterSet)` does not work then. It *does* work, however, when I don't override `get_table_data`.

Right now, the filters, which appear as normal and are passed normally, just don't filter. It always shows the data according to `get_table_data`, no matter which filter string I enter.

How can I get it all? I want define my custum table data *and* have my defined filters work on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK now, I figured it out myself...

Instead of overriding `get_table_data`, I had to override `get_queryset` , like so

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Invoice.objects.filter(invoice_owner__username=self.request.user).order_by('invoice_due_date')
    return qs
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried add `table_data` attribute to class instead of overriding `get_table_data`?

EDIT:
I think you should override `get_filterset` function. Something like this:

```
    def get_filterset(self, filterset_class):
        filterset = super().get_filterset(filterset_class)
        return filterset.filter(invoice_owner__username=self.request.user).order_by('i
nvoice_due_date')
```

Comment: that gives _'PersonalView' object has no attribute 'super'_

Nevermind, I have figured out a solution. See below. Thanks for your effort, though! :)

Comment: Sure, `super` is built in function, just made a 'typo' here. Edited my anwser, hope that works ;)

Comment: no, it gave: 'InvoiceFilter' object has no attribute 'filter'

Anyway, like I said, I solved it with get_queryset. (just can't accept my own answer yet)